# Extract the last information of url in Python

Tags: python

This is the url that I have `https://math.berkeley.edu/~jcalder/126F15/hw1.pdf` and I want to get only `hw1.pdf` of that url.

And, I have used `urlparse.urlparse(url).path` in the library `urlparse` and it returned `~jcalder/126F15/hw1.pdf` which is not what I wanted.

Hence, can anyone show me how to do it please ?

Comment: `'~jcalder/126F15/hw1.pdf'.split('/')[-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
urlparse.urlparse(url).path.rsplit("/", 1)[-1]
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer.